# combining 2 SQL queries from different tables

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-order-by, union

I have an appointment database containing doctors and past appointment.
When a user wants to schedule an appointment to a doctor, he picks a residency, afterwards he will be shown the doctors according to that residency. now the part where it gets tricky:

The doctors are to be shown in the order of past appointments, meaning that if I were to visit two cardiologists in the past, the last one I had an appointment with will be shown first, after him the other one, and after them all other cardiologists I never had an appointment with.

For that I need to look for my past appointments with cardiologists and sort them in descending order by date and then go to all doctors and just add the other ones to the bottom of the list.

I'm trying this query:

```
(
select distinct pastappointments.doctorID from pastappointments where
     pastappointments.insuredID = 1  and pastappointments.residency='cardio'
order by pastappointments.appTime desc
)
union (
select employees.employeeID from employees where  
employees.Residency='cardio'  and employees.employeeID not in (
select distinct pastappointments.doctorID from pastappointments where  
pastappointments.insuredID = 1  and pastappointments.residency='cardio'
))
```

The problem I'm having is mainly when running the first query above the union command, without parentheses I'm getting the correct order, once the parentheses the result of the query changes to a wrong one.

I'm using MySQL.

I wish to do this using one query and not two different ones, but I just can't seem to find a way to do so without losing the descending order I need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want results in a particular order, then you need to specify `order by` in the outermost query.

In MySQL, this is *after* the `union`.  I also strongly recommend `union all` instead of `union`, unless you explicitly want to incur the overhead of removing duplicates:

```
(select pa.doctorID, max(pa.appTime) as last_apptime
 from pastappointments pa
 where pa.insuredID = 1 and pa.residency = 'cardio'
 group by pa.doctorID
) union all
(select e.employeeID, NULL as last_apptime
 from employees e
 where e.Residency = 'cardio' and
       e.employeeID not in (select pa.doctorID
                            from pastappointments pa
                            where pa.insuredID = 1 and       
                                  pa.residency = 'cardio'
                           )
)
order by (last_apptime is not null) desc, last_apptime desc;
```

This returns two columns.  If you want one column, just use a subquery:

```
select t.doctorID
from (<above query without orderby) t
order by (last_apptime is not null) desc, last_apptime desc;
```

I should also note the use of the `group by` in the first query.  This is needed to get the correct last appointment time.

And, if I assume that all doctors are employees, this can be much simplified:

```
 select e.employeeID
 from employees e left join
      (select pa.doctorID, max(apptime) as last_apptime
       from pastappointments pa
       where pa.insuredID = 1 and pa.residency = 'cardio'
       group by pa.doctorId
      ) pa
      on e.EmployeeId = pa.DoctorId
 where e.Residency = 'cardio' -- or pa.doctorId is not null
 order by (last_apptime is not null) desc, last_apptime;
```

This also assumes that `e.Residency` is the same as `pa.residency`.  If that is not the case, then the `or` condition is needed.

This is a more reasonable way to write the query (assuming all doctors are employees).

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response!
your first suggestion worked but when i tried using the simpler suggestion it notified me about an unexpected "where".
another small question i have, can i use the sub query while using the main one?so that all i get back from the DB is the doctor's ID's numbers?

Comment: You are missing the ON clause for your LEFT JOIN (`pa.doctorID = e.employeeID`).

Answer (score 0):

You have to surround both queries by an outer query and apply **order by** to it.

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT DISCTINCT pastappointments.doctorID 
    FROM pastappointments 
    WHERE pastappointments.insuredID = 1 
    AND pastappointments.residency='cardio')
   UNION 
    (SELECT employees.employeeID 
     FROM employees 
     WHERE employees.Residency='cardio' 
     AND employees.employeeID NOT IN
       (SELECT DISTINCT pastappointments.doctorID 
        FROM pastappointments 
        WHERE pastappointments.insuredID = 1 
        AND pastappointments.residency='cardio'))
  )
 ORDER BY pastappointments.appTime DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a LEFT JOIN and replace missing appointment times with a value wich will be ordered last.

```
select employees.employeeID 
from employees
left join pastappointments
  on  pastappointments.insuredID = 1
  and pastappointments.residency='cardio'
  and pastappointments.doctorID = employees.employeeID
group by employees.employeeID
where employees.Residency='cardio'
order by coalesce(max(pastappointments.appTime), cast(0 as datetime)) desc
```